# Extracting localities with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract some phrases (localities) from some strings, and have put several examples below. The function searches the text after this first ref and would go to the first `.`, but ignoring cases like `km.`, `ca.` and `U.S.` (the latter for when it is U.S.A.).

However, the ca within the pattern in the function ends up ignoring the `a.` in `Colombia.` in the first example. If I test with `Colombie`, it works as expected.
All the others are working, only the first example doesn't work yet.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

places <- tibble(
  text = c(
    "versity Studies No. 19; ref. 1259] Villavicencio, Río Orinoco system, Colombia. Holotype: FMNH 56646 [ex CM 5463]. Paratypes: (6) ",
    "versity Studies No. 19; ref. 1259] Villavicencio, Río Orinoco system, Colombie. Holotype: FMNH 56646 [ex CM 5463]. Paratypes: (6) ",
    "ions No. 457 (art. 17); ref. 2247] Roadside pool, 3 kilometers south of Progreso, Yucatán, southeastern Mexico. Holotype: UMMZ 102144. Paratypes: UMMZ 102145 (3). •Syn",
    "for 2001); ref. 27036] La Sapayera stream, near the bridge km. 2 vía Guadalupe-Florencia, 1°59'27\"N, 75°45'08\"W, afluent of La Viciosa stream, río Suaza system, upper Magdalena, Cachimba trail, Municipality of Guadalupe, Department of Huila, Colombia, elevation 952 meters. Holotype: IUQ 422. Par",
    "); ref. 30495] Rio Iguaçu, ca. 25°43'S, 49°44'W, Serrinha, Paraná, Brazil. Holotype: FMN",
    ". 4 (no. 2) (art. 7); ref. 1261] Corumba, río Otuquis, Ascunción, Paraguay. Holo",
    "); ref. 14367] Not: Puerto Mexico [Coatzacoalcos], Veracruz State, Isthmus of Tehuantepec, Mexico [probably Panama]. Holotype",
    "hia v. 7; ref. 168] Upper tributaries of Nueces River, Texas, U.S.A. Lectotype: BMNH 1883.12.14.107. Paralectotype"
  )
)


places %>% 
  mutate(
    type_locality = stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=ref.\\s[:digit:]{1,6}\\]\\s).*?[^\\s(km|ca|U\\.S\\.)\\.](?=\\.\\s)")) %>% 
  relocate(type_locality)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   type_locality                                                            text 
#>   <chr>                                                                    <chr>
#> 1 "Villavicencio, Río Orinoco system, Colombia. Holotype: FMNH 56646 [ex ~ "ver~
#> 2 "Villavicencio, Río Orinoco system, Colombie"                            "ver~
#> 3 "Roadside pool, 3 kilometers south of Progreso, Yucatán, southeastern M~ "ion~
#> 4 "La Sapayera stream, near the bridge km. 2 vía Guadalupe-Florencia, 1°5~ "for~
#> 5 "Rio Iguaçu, ca. 25°43'S, 49°44'W, Serrinha, Paraná, Brazil"             "); ~
#> 6 "Corumba, río Otuquis, Ascunción, Paraguay"                              ". 4~
#> 7 "Not: Puerto Mexico [Coatzacoalcos], Veracruz State, Isthmus of Tehuant~ "); ~
#> 8 "Upper tributaries of Nueces River, Texas, U.S.A"                        "hia~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `E.] & Hildebrand [S. F.] 1916:275, Pl. 18 [Field Museum of Natural History, Publications, Zoölogical Series v. 10 (no. 15); ref. 2962] Río Gatún, Monte Liria, Canal Zone, Panama. Holotype: FMNH 8944 (not 8941). Paratypes: CAS 59736 (2); Géry coll` is another example

Comment: `[^\s(km|ca|U\.S\.)\.]` is a corrupt pattern since you are trying to match char *sequences* with a character class. Character classes only match single chars.

Comment: Try `"(?<=ref\\.\\s[0-9]{1,6}]\\s)(?:\\b(?:km|ca|U\\.S)\\.|.)*?(?=\\.\\s)"`

Comment: Could you explain the `(?:\\b(?:km|ca|U\\.S)\\.|.)` section? With all these examples it works, but not with the whole dataset.

Comment: Any char or the exceptions. What doesn't it work with?

Comment: If that expression fails the problem is that your exception list is not complete.

Comment: It's working now! My bad! Could you write this as an answer to me accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=ref\\.\\s[0-9]{1,6}]\\s)(?:\\b(?:km|ca|U\\.S)\\.|.)*?(?=\\.\\s)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xpnrCo/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=ref\.\s[0-9]{1,6}]\s)`  - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `ref.` + whitespace + one to six digits + `]` + whitespace
- `(?:\b(?:km|ca|U\.S)\.|.)*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, whole words `km`, `ca`, or `U.S` + a `.` char, or any char (but a line break char)
- `(?=\.\s)`  - a positive lookahead that requires a `.` char + a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.